# How is the Query Elevation Component in Solr implemented in Lucene?

Tags: java, solr, lucene

I'd like to know because I want to implement it in core Lucene.

Comment: @curiosa I apologize, I phrased the question incorrectly. I wanted to know how it is implemented in Lucene. I've edited the title now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Query Elevation Component is a Solr specific component. The source code [is available on Github](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/515af6d3ecc5ea1b3754776f9ce4e39857f99734/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/handler/component/QueryElevationComponent.java).

In general it [modifies the existing query](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/515af6d3ecc5ea1b3754776f9ce4e39857f99734/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/handler/component/QueryElevationComponent.java#L500) and [inserts itself into the available sort order](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/515af6d3ecc5ea1b3754776f9ce4e39857f99734/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/handler/component/QueryElevationComponent.java#L527).

That way it doesn't affect anything else in the query except for what should be changed as part of the elevate component. It also keeps any other parameters/features available to other components in the chain.

The `getBoostDocs` method resolves the docids to their priority position.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. The thing is, I'm new to programming in general. So it's a bit hard for me to follow their code on Github. Could you please elaborate a bit more on how "it modifies the existing query", and how it "inserts itself into the available sort order"?